# HTML tabs not preloading

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I am having a problem with tabbed content. I downloaded a very nicely styled content tabber done in HTML/CSS/Javascript.

The problem is that while the page is loading it shows all the content at once. Only once it has finished loading will it put it in the tabs.

Does anyone know why it would do this? I am thinking something to do with the JS and unfortunately I don't know anything about JS.

I can post the JS code if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is with the JS code and your page. I'm guessing you've built the page for all browser which is the correct way of doing it. But I'm guessing you're then hiding content with jQuery? This slows down the page download speed as it will be running always. The best way to do this sort of tab structure would be to build the landing page and content with additional links to load new source data from an out-soured page. Similar to an ajax request function to load new page html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that your HTML (document) is loaded first prior to the JS being applied. So you are going to initially see all of the HTML content.

One solution to resolve this is to hide the content via CSS initially and then show it once the JS has converted the content into tabbed content.

A basic example of this can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/86pzN/

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();  
        $('#tabs-2,#tabs-3').show();
    }, 3000);
});
```

The some of the tabs can be hidden via css and then shown after the Tab functionality has been applied.

**p.s.** I have added the `setTimeout` code here to mimic a page loading the HTML slowly before running the JS code.

Comment: Thank you for this! Much appreciated. I wasn't sure how to go about it.